# Regex to remove consecutive special characters greater than specified count

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I would like to remove all appearances of the character `/` and `\` in a string if it appears consecutively more than twice, using Regex. This means, if a string contains `abc////////////////////////def`, I would like to get all `/` removed. However, it should not remove "the `/` in `http://`.

Could someone please suggest?

Comment: Look into **quantifiers**. This is pretty elementary stuff.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `/{3,}`, which will match 3 or more occurrences of the `/` character.

```
var result = Regex.Replace("abc///def", "/{3,}", "");
```

**Update:** to reply to your comment, the `*` character is a metacharacter in regex, which holds a special meaning, so you need to escape it. Try this: `\*{3,}`. If you want to combine both characters, you can use a character class: `[/*]{3,}`. A character class is denoted by the square brackets. Inside a character class you don't need to escape metacharacters, which is why I simply list `*` inside without escaping it as I did earlier.

Comment: That worked for "/". How can I apply the same for the character "*". I get an error when I tried the same for "*". I am new to this Regex thing, hence these pretty basic questions.

Comment: @Thomas I've updated my answer to reply to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use [negative look-behind assertion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#zerowidth_negative_lookbehind_assertion):

```
@"(?<!https?:)/{2,}|\\{2,}"
```

For example:

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"(?<!https?:)/{2,}|\\{2,}");
Console.WriteLine(pattern.Replace(@"http://example.com", ""));
Console.WriteLine(pattern.Replace(@"abc//////////def", ""));
Console.WriteLine(pattern.Replace(@"abc\\\\\\\\\\def", ""));
```

prints

```
http://example.com
abcdef
abcdef
```